# How to enable CDN CSS in Brackets, Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, cdn, cross-site, adobe-brackets

I am using [brackets](http://brackets.io/) to edit a simple HTML document. The document refers to a CSS hosted on a CDN:

```
<head>
    <title>Test server monitor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

This call works perfectly from the production server. However, when loaded in Chrome using the Live Preview mode, the external CSS is not loaded. I guess the reason is some cross-site limitation.

**How do I allow Chrome to use A CSS from a CDN called from a local file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this relatively easy, simply change your `href` to:

`http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`

The `http:` ensures the correct protocol is being implemented for the request.